# Laravel 5 : How to get path name from URL?

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel , I come across a situation where I need to get the path name from url.

e.g.

> www.example.com/timeslot

In above example I want to fetch "timeslot" in my controller

```
public function login()
{
$url = URL::current();
echo "timeslot"; //I want to print only "timeslot" here.
}
```

Comment: Try this: `$url = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();`

Answer (score 9):

simply use

```
 $request->path();
```

The path method returns the request's path information. So, if the incoming request is targeted at `www.example.com/timeslot`, the path method will return `timeslot`.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Answer (score 7):

Hello to retrieve a uri segment in laravel use it

```
$segment = Request::segment(1);
```

inside the blade view like this

```
{!! Request::segment(1) !!}
```

this will return the first segment of your project uri

www.example.com/timeslot

> timeslot

Comment: I was looking for a solution like this for a while. Was stuck using $request->path() and a whole bunch workarounds and regex to get parts of the url that I needed. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the `path`

```
public function login(){
    $url =\Request::path();
    echo $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the path, like so.

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    $url = $request->path();
    return view('home')->with('url', $url);
}
```

and in your view

```
{{ $url }}
```